# Существует ли css способ задать text-overflow:ellipsis для select?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

Возможно ли добавить `text-overflow: ellipsis;` для `select`, чтобы он выглядел также как и `div` - если не хватает места тексту, то в конце появляется многоточие. Понятно, что многоточие можно добавить с помощью `js`, но хотелось бы легкого `css` решения:

```css
.select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 34.5px;
  padding: 5px 22px 3px 11px;
  font: 400 16px/24px sans-serif;
  color: #464a4c;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat right 6px top 13px;
  border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option selected>select самый большой текст с длинное название</option>
  <option value="1">1 самый большой текст с длинное название</option>
  <option value="2">2 самый большой текст с длинное название</option>
  <option value="3">3 самый большой текст с длинное название</option>
</select>

<br>

<div class="select">div самый большой текст с длинное название</div>
```

Comment: Насколько мне известно простого цсс решения нет и жизнь боль. И это нормально. Кастомные контролы довольно часто пишут именно потому что цсс решения нет.

Comment: Добавить непосредственно к select или к option? Если к select, то у меня в FF всё нормально отображается.

Comment: к select, когда выпадающий список закрыт